# Xcode I collection view I queue urlsession datatasks within cellForRowAtIndexpath function

Tags: swift, xcode, urlsession

Here's the code that gets the imageView of the cell at indexpath.row, the url, and does the urlSession. But it downloads everything at once and that's not good. I want to only start a new urlsession when the one before it finished downloading. How can I accomplish this?

```
    let image = cell.viewWithTag(10) as! UIImageView
    let url = URL(string: categories[indexPath.row].imageURL)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIView.transition(with: image, duration: 0.1, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                image.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }, completion: nil)
        }
        }
        .resume()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cellForRowAtIndexpath` is called when the cell is about to be shown , so in your current code it will download the image every appearance of the cell , you need to use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) to take benefit of many things including the automatic cache

Also it's better to create outlets for the elements inside the cell instead of the tags

```
let image = cell.viewWithTag(10) as! UIImageView
```